# Получить значение из array

Tags: php, json

```
Array
(
    [id] => 164770127965849081
    [app] => 54680000
    [user_id] => 
    [presence] => offline
    [presence_details] => Array
        (
            [presence] => offline
        )

    [props] => Array
        (
            [$last_seen] => 2016-07-18T10:06:39
            [$sessions] => 1
            [$longitude] => 36.00000
            [$country] => Russia
            [$score] => 26
            [$active_device_guid] => ffffffff-aaaa-4444-cccc-ec82488ff21b
            [$name_placeholder] => honey-brown-sandwich
            [$latitude] => 50.0000
            [$conversations_emails] => 2
            [$email] => 123@123.com
            [$device_type] => mobile
            [$last_contacted] => 2016-07-16T16:20:16
            [$initial_referrer] => https://yandex.ru/
            [$region] => Belgorodskaya Oblast'
            [$last_session_referrer] => https://yandex.ru/
            [$initial_referrer_domain] => yandex.ru
            [$viewed_products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Двухфазный кондиционер №1 Q3 для сильно поврежд волос
                    [1] => Масло №2 Q3 для поврежденных волос
                    [2] => Набор для заботливой мамы
                    [3] => Сыворотка для волос Манго ESTEL MOHITO 60 мл
                    [4] => Масло-блеск №3 Q3 для всех типов волос
                )

            [$city] => Belgorod
        )

    [props_custom] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Требуется получить [$email] из [props] => Array

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? И где тут json?

Comment: не получается получить [$email] из [props] => Array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В PHP есть функции `json_encode` и `json_decode`, которые кодируют и декодируют `json` соответственно, ну а после декодирования получаем обычный массив.

Обратиться к полю `$email` можно так:

```
$massive['props']['email']
```

А вообще это обычные вложенные массивы и обращаться к их элементам нужно так же, как и в большинстве других языков программирования

Comment: Анатолий, код приведённый в вопросе получен после json_decode($data, true). Я не знаю каким именно способом получить $email, поэтому и задал вопрос

Comment: добавил пример в ответ

Comment: Если помогло, не забывай про галочку слева от ответа )

Comment: Анатолий, спасибо за пример, как только проверю, если поможет, обязательно отмечу ваш ответ как правильный.

Comment: Ключи массивов могут быть не только с $, но даже и Русскими символами)
На текущий момент не ясно что требуется. Можно просто обратиться к ключу массива как показано в ответе. А можно воспользоваться array_search()
Проблема то в чём?

Comment: @it-blog.club проблема в том, что я не знаю как это применить, потому что в php совсем не силён

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев $massive["props"]['email']